# How do you only load certain contents in HTML table into R

Tags: html, r

So I'm trying to get the table on this website into R (it's for homework), the website is https://www.4icu.org/top-universities-north-america/. Naturally I tried to do this, which looks fine, but under variable "Institution" it took the description part too.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url2017<-getURL("https://www.4icu.org/top-universities-north-america/")
doc2017<-htmlParse(url2017,encoding="utf-8")
rank2017<-readHTMLTable(doc2017, header=TRUE, which=1)
```

So instead of just the University names, it also has the short introduction underneath it. How can I just get the University name into R (I tried to come up a loop to contain just names but didn't work). 
Thanks for yall help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never managed to use `XML` in a reliable manner, I just find it tedious.
Much better to use `rvest`, and then use [Selector Gadget](http://selectorgadget.com) to find the CSS selectors.

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://www.4icu.org/top-universities-north-america/"
vec <- read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes(".text-left .lead") %>% html_text()
head(vec, 3)
# " Massachusetts Institute of Technology" 
# " Stanford University" 
# " Harvard University"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This look so much better.